# Github Pages shows blank page after deployment react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm tryin' to learn reactjs and made a simple weather create-react-app project (https://github.com/zxcminusminus/react-weather/tree/master) which I'd like to deploy to Github pages using gh-pages. So my app worked perfectly on localhost but when I tryed to deploy it on gh pages I got blank page. To deploy it I added "homepage", "deploy" and "predeploy" fields in package.json just like in tutorials, ran "npm install gh-pages" command, then ran "npm run deploy" command.  I read like 10 similar questions and followed some of the tips. But nothing worked(
Here is gh pages settings [gh-pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hjJm.png)

I tried adding "-d build" to deploy script like "deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d build"

I tried replacing Route with HashRoute from this [index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edoWl.png) [App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m61U.png) to this [index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwULv.png) [App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H53Y3.png)

I tried some little changes like changing default path in Route from "/" to this <Route path={"/react-weather"} element={}/> but still blank page(

P.S. forgive me for these links instead of embedded images, stackoverflow says i dont have 10 reputation points yet:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this file](https://github.com/zxcminusminus/react-weather/blob/gh-pages/index.html) you can see that paths start with `/` e.g. `<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.0065d37f.js">`

Paths in gh-pages must start with `./`

`homepage` in `package.json` have to be set to `./`?

You will also need to use `HashRouter`, because gh-pages doesn't redirect all traffic to `index.html`